# Python C, tbb, calling a function from multiple threads

Tags: python, c++, c, tbb

As a learning process of Python C API I am trying to call a Python function inside of functor passed to tbb parallel_for.
Operation of calling the function crashes instance of Python process. 
I am not doing anything not thread safe. I get the item from a list and I then call a Python function with the item passed as an argument to the function. In the end I set the item back to the list. Any hints what have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely that you forgot to grab Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) when you call Python function back from C++. For example, TBB module for Python [implements this](https://github.com/01org/tbb/blob/tbb_2017/python/tbb.i#L75) using [swig](/questions/tagged/swig):

```
class PyCaller : public swig::SwigPtr_PyObject {
public:
  using swig::SwigPtr_PyObject::SwigPtr_PyObject; // gets constructors

  void operator()() const {
    SWIG_PYTHON_THREAD_BEGIN_BLOCK;
    PyObject* r = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs((PyObject*)*this, NULL);
    if(r) Py_DECREF(r);
    SWIG_PYTHON_THREAD_END_BLOCK;
  }
};

// Usage:
tbb::task_group tg;
void enqueue( PyObject *c ) {
    tg.run( PyCaller(c) );
}
```

And you can see how SWIG implements it - [here](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/python/pythreads.swg#L16).

Other options to consider include using Numba's [`@cfunc(nopython=True)`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/cfunc.html) decorator and Cython's [`nogil`](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#releasing-the-gil) attribute which both make function faster and enable Python's function to run in parallel as they remove GIL from the compiled function.